# Is it possible to import/export all the information of all products that i have in my inventory to an excel file?

Tags: expresso-store

So what i want is to export/import all the information, especially the price modifiers information, of all products that are in my inventory, to an excel file. So not to a PDF.

I've tried to do this using the Zenbu module. But this does not support Exp:resso Store. Is there any other module out there that is able to do this? Or is this maybe a feature within Store already? If not, maybe this is an interesting idea for a future feature in Store?

Any information is helpfull!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm currently writing an import/export module specifically for Expresso Store sites that allows you to export to CSV, modify then re-import back to EE. Ping me an email and I can update you once the Beta is ready. peter@peteralewis.com

Comment: @PeterLewis I've sent you an email

Answer (score 1):

Just to add a precision, exporting can be done from [Zenbu](http://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu), but through a Zenbu add-on called [Hokoku](http://zenbustudio.com/software/hokoku), which exports the displayed data in HTML, JSON and CSV (Excel-readable) for now.

If Exp:resso Store isn't displaying as you want in Zenbu (and in consequence in the exported file), it could be that Exp:resso doesn't have Zenbu cell display compatibility yet. The fallback is to display the contents of the data stored in exp_channel_data instead. Better display/compatibility can be added by the third-party developer by adding a few functions in their ft.my_field.php file.

Zenbu third-party add-on developer documentation to add this functionality can be found [here](http://zenbustudio.com/software/dev/zenbu).

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, Store doesn't natively support Zenbu. Normally if you need to export data, the best way is to write a raw SQL query that will format the data exactly as you need it (this could vary a lot, because each product has a number of variations and SKUs which won't fit exactly into a two dimensional excel spreadsheet/CSV anyway).